# Creating INSERT and UPDATE queries in Postgresql using Ada Gnatcoll

Tags: postgresql, ada

I've got the SELECT query working on my Postgresql (version 10.10 running on Slackware 14.2) setup, but have gotten a bit stuck trying to figure out INSERT and UPDATE. Reading the documentation, I've tried constructing queries, but fail for what is probably my lack of comprehension.

All I'm looking for is the simplest of examples that allow me to use Gnatcoll.

Say I have a table "xyzzy", with two columns: "id" of type integer (autoincrementing and the primary key), and "term" of type text.

My first insertion might be:

`INSERT INTO xyzzy (term) VALUES ('foo');`

Following that, an update:

`UPDATE xyzzy SET term = 'bar' WHERE id = 1;`

The examples in the Postgres documentation were detailed enough for SELECT; I just struggle to understand INSERT and UPDATE.

Any help gratefully received.

Update: I've gotten a bit further and can now do a basic INSERT using the following:
`GNATCOLL.SQL.Exec.Execute (My_DB, "INSERT INTO xyzzy (term) VALUES ('bar');");`

Next step is to figure out how to do it properly using the SQL_Query type.

Comment: The SQL looks OK, so what is your problem? Is it that you can’t figure out how to express it using GNATColl? or that you get some weird compilation error? or that it compiles but doesn’t have the effect you expected? We normally like to see a [mcve]

Comment: The former: more lack of understanding than anything else.

Comment: The GNATcoll documentation has a great tutorial containing a hands-on example that illustrates how to interact with databases (see [here](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnatcoll-db/html/gnatcoll-db_ug/sql.html#database-example)). Moreover, instead of using SQL statements, you might also want to consider using the ORM to add and update database records as discussed [here](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnatcoll-db/html/gnatcoll-db_ug/sql.html#modifying-objects-in-the-orm).

Comment: I've read through that, and it was helpful in working out how to use SELECT. I just struggled with the other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an existing PostgreSQL database named `mydb2` with a table created using

**persons.sql**

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE persons (
    person_uid   uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name   VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    last_name    VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
);

GRANT SELECT ON persons TO deedee;
GRANT INSERT ON persons TO deedee;
GRANT UPDATE ON persons TO deedee;
GRANT DELETE ON persons TO deedee;
```

then after generating the required Ada datatypes via

```
$ gnatcoll_postgres2ada -dbmodel dschema.txt
```

with

**dschema.txt**

```
| TABLE             | persons |          || The contents of person |
| person_uid        | TEXT    | PK       || Auto-generated id      |
| first_name        | TEXT    | NOT NULL || First name             |
| last_name         | TEXT    | NOT NULL || Last name              |
```

the following code illustrates how to use `SQL_Insert`, `SQL_Update` and `SQL_Delete`. Please note that I omitted the error checking for simplicity (see, for example, the function `GNATCOLL.SQL.Exec.Success`).

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;            use Ada.Text_IO;
with GNATCOLL.Traces;        use GNATCOLL.Traces;
with GNATCOLL.SQL.Postgres;  use GNATCOLL.SQL.Postgres;
with GNATCOLL.SQL.Exec;      use GNATCOLL.SQL.Exec;
with GNATCOLL.VFS;           use GNATCOLL.VFS;
with GNATCOLL.SQL.Inspect;   use GNATCOLL.SQL.Inspect;
with GNATCOLL.SQL;           use GNATCOLL.SQL;
with Database;

procedure Main is
   
   DB_Descr : GNATCOLL.SQL.Exec.Database_Description;
   --  Datebase description.
   
   DB : GNATCOLL.SQL.Exec.Database_Connection;
   -- Database connection.
   
   procedure Dump_Table;
   --  Dumps the content of the table "persons" to standard output.
   
   ----------------
   -- Dump_Table --
   ----------------
   
   procedure Dump_Table is
      
      S : constant SQL_Query :=
        SQL_Select (Fields => Database.Persons.First_Name &  --  0
                              Database.Persons.Last_Name,    --  1
                    From   => Database.Persons);
      
      R : Forward_Cursor;
      
   begin

      Put_Line ("---------- TABLE ----------");
      
      --  Perform the actual query, show results if OK.
      R.Fetch (DB, S);
      if Success (DB) then
         while Has_Row (R) loop
            Put_Line (Value (R, 0) & " " & Value (R, 1));
            Next (R);
         end loop;

      else
         Put_Line ("FAILED");         
      end if;
      New_Line;
      
   end Dump_Table;      

begin
  
   -- Database description.
   DB_Descr := GNATCOLL.SQL.Postgres.Setup
     (Database => "mydb2",
      User     => "deedee",
      Host     => "localhost",
      Password => "xxxx");

   -- Database connection.
   DB := DB_Descr.Build_Connection;
   
   --  Insert two records.   
   declare
      I1 : constant SQL_Query :=
        SQL_Insert (Values => (Database.Persons.First_Name = "John") &
                              (Database.Persons.Last_Name  = "Doe"));
   
      I2 : constant SQL_Query :=
        SQL_Insert (Values => (Database.Persons.First_Name = "Jane") &
                              (Database.Persons.Last_Name  = "Doe"));
   begin
      Execute (Connection => DB, Query => I1);
      Execute (Connection => DB, Query => I2);
      Dump_Table;
   end;
   
   --  Update one of the records.
   declare
      U : constant SQL_Query := 
        SQL_Update (Table => Database.Persons,
                    Set   => (Database.Persons.First_Name = "Johnny"),
                    Where => (Database.Persons.First_Name = "John") and
                             (Database.Persons.Last_Name  = "Doe" ));
   begin      
      Execute (Connection => DB, Query => U);
      Dump_Table;
   end;
   
   --  Delete one of the records.
   declare
      D : constant SQL_Query := 
        SQL_Delete (From  => Database.Persons,
                    Where => (Database.Persons.First_Name = "Jane") and
                             (Database.Persons.Last_Name  = "Doe" ));
   begin      
      Execute (Connection => DB, Query => D);
      Dump_Table;
   end;  

   --  Commit changes to the database.
   Commit (DB);
   
   Free (DB);  --  for all connections you have opened
   Free (DB_Descr);

end Main;
```

**output**

```
$ ./obj/main
---------- TABLE ----------
John Doe
Jane Doe

---------- TABLE ----------
Jane Doe
Johnny Doe

---------- TABLE ----------
Johnny Doe
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I'll give this a go tomorrow. Looks like it fills in the missing gaps in my understanding.